# MISSING SESSION error message when logging into Heroku

Tags: heroku

When attempting to log in to Heroku it will not allow me to log in and get an error message 'MISSING SESSION'

I can't log a call with Heroku support as I can't log in!

I have 2nd authentication turned on and have entered the code on the authenticator app, the log in accepts this as a big green tick appears, but then I get the error message

Has anyone had had this error when attempting to log in and is there a solution?!!

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure to log out from all previous sessions still opened, on all your devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).